# pydantic and pylint conflict E1137

Tags: python, pydantic, pylint

I am using **pydantic** in my code along with **pylint** for code validation. The following code appears to be valid to me, but pylint is displaying an E1137 error message. Can you help me identify what might be wrong?

I need update dictionary inside object.

```py
from pydantic import Field, BaseModel


class Object(BaseModel):
    data: dict[str, str] = Field(default={}, description="description")

    def update_data(self, values: dict[str, str]) -> None:
        """Update self dictionary."""
        for key, value in values.items():
            self.data[key] = value


obj = Object()
obj.update_data(values={"key": "value"})
print(obj.data)  # {'key': 'value'}
```

```
pylint --disable=all --enable=E1137 my_script.py

E1137: 'self.data' does not support item assignment (unsupported-assignment-operation)
```

```
pip list

pydantic           2.4.2
pydantic_core      2.10.1
pydantic-settings  2.0.3
pylint             3.0.2
```

Comment: You're running pylint, not mypy.

Comment: It seems like an issue in pylint. I'd suggest creating a GitHub issue.

Comment: Or maybe an issue in pydantic, in the stubs. With pydantic 1, the error does not happen. On a sidenote, I switched from pylint to ruff recently, which on top of being much faster does not raise any error here :)

Comment: switched to ruff, really good tool!